# CaptainCasa framework: There is missing option to set focus on Page Bean Component

Tags: java, jsp

When it is used Page Bean Component it is missing method "setRequestfocus" similar to other components.
Do you have similar ?
If not can this be exposed ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the focus to a page bean/ page bean component directly. But of course you can assign the focus to some control that is part of the page bean component ("just normal" focus management).

This means:

1. define the corresponding control inside the page bean/ page bean component so that it can receive the focus by program logic (attribute "requestfocus" etc. - please check Demo Workplace: General > Focus Management > Request focus by application).
2. expose the setting of the focus setting into some public method
3. call this public method by the user of the page bean.